# Composite primary key query

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, composite-primary-key

I have a composite primary key. The keys are in turn two entities. I want to query based on the entities inside the primary key.

My intention is to query on the primary key something like this

```
Criteria projCriteria = session.createCriteria(ProjectDetailsRO.class);
        projCriteria.createAlias("projectUsers", "projectUsers");
        projCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("projectUsers.pk.users.email", leadUserEmail));
```

But I get an exception 
could not resolve property: pk.users.email of: com.ett.repository.ProjectUsers

I want to query based on the user(of PK class). How to give Alias for the entity which is inside the PK class(UserDetailsRO). PLEASE HELP..!!

The entities and the relations are as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PROJECT_USERS")
@AssociationOverrides({
@AssociationOverride(name="pk.users", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id")), 
@AssociationOverride(name="pk.project", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="project_id"))
})
public class ProjectUsers {

    private ProjectUserPK pk= new ProjectUserPK();




    @EmbeddedId
    public ProjectUserPK getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(ProjectUserPK pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Transient
    public ProjectDetailsRO getProjects() {
        return getPk().getProject();
    }

    public void setProjects(ProjectDetailsRO projects) {
        getPk().setProject(projects);
    }


    @Transient
    public UserDetailsRO getUsers() {
        return getPk().getUsers();
    }

    public void setUsers(UserDetailsRO users) {
        getPk().setUsers(users);
    }



    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((isLead == null) ? 0 : isLead.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((pk == null) ? 0 : pk.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ProjectUsers other = (ProjectUsers) obj;
        if (isLead == null) {
            if (other.isLead != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!isLead.equals(other.isLead))
            return false;
        if (pk == null) {
            if (other.pk != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!pk.equals(other.pk))
            return false;
        return true;
    }



}

THE PRIMARY KEY CLASS
----------------------

@Embeddable
public class ProjectUserPK implements Serializable{

    private ProjectDetailsRO project;

    private UserDetailsRO users;

    @ManyToOne
    public ProjectDetailsRO getProject() {
        return project;
    }

    public void setProject(ProjectDetailsRO project) {
        this.project = project;
    }


    @ManyToOne
    public UserDetailsRO getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(UserDetailsRO users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((project == null) ? 0 : project.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((users == null) ? 0 : users.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ProjectUserPK other = (ProjectUserPK) obj;
        if (project == null) {
            if (other.project != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!project.equals(other.project))
            return false;
        if (users == null) {
            if (other.users != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!users.equals(other.users))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


}

The Main ENtity
=====================


@Entity
@Table(name="PROJECT_DTLS")
public class ProjectDetailsRO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="PROJECT_ID")
    private Long projectId;


    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="pk.project", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProjectUsers>projectUsers = new LinkedList<ProjectUsers>();




    public void addUser(UserDetailsRO user,  Character lead){
        ProjectUsers association = new ProjectUsers();
        association.setUsers(user);
        association.setProjects(this);
        association.setIsLead(lead);

        this.projectUsers.add(association);
        user.getProjectUsers().add(association);
    }

    public List<ProjectUsers> getProjectUsers() {
        return projectUsers;
    }

    public void setProjectUsers(List<ProjectUsers> projectUsers) {
        this.projectUsers = projectUsers;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide the UserDetailsRO class, so we'll assume that the 'email' property in it is property annotized.  If that's the case, try creating aliases in your Criteria down to the 'users'.  Something like:

```
Criteria projCriteria = session.createCriteria(ProjectDetailsRO.class);
projCriteria.createAlias("projectUsers", "projectUsers");
projCriteria.createAlias("pk", "projectUsers.pk");
projCriteria.createAlias("users", "pk.users");
projCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("users.email", leadUserEmail));
```

Comment: Yes thats the property. I tried doing it the way you told. Iguess the property names and the aliases should be kept the other way.i.e(projCriteria.createAlias("projectUsers.pk", "pk"); The query is generated but gives error 
Unknown column 'users3_.EMAIL' in 'where clause'

Comment: Query generated
 select
        this_.PROJECT_ID as PROJECT1_1_1_,
        this_.CREATED_DATE as CREATED2_1_1_,
        this_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT3_1_1_,
        this_.NAME as NAME1_1_,
        this_.TYPE as TYPE1_1_,
        projectuse1_.project_id as project2_6_0_,
        projectuse1_.user_id as user3_6_0_,
        projectuse1_.isLead as isLead6_0_ 
    from
        PROJECT_DTLS this_ 
    inner join
        PROJECT_USERS projectuse1_ 
            on this_.PROJECT_ID=projectuse1_.project_id 
    where
        users3_.EMAIL=? 
        and projectuse1_.isLead=? and it gives error

Comment: Could you please suggest me where I am making mistake? Please let me know if I need to provide any more details.

Comment: that sql query looks flawed...the 'where' clause is referencing a table with alias 'users3_', but there isn't one declared in the 'from'/'join' clauses.  is the users table mapped in Hibernate?

Comment: Yes that user table is mapped. I need to query based on the  user Name which is inside the UserDetailsRO.